# EXCEL カスタムリボン：ドロップダウンリストを選択前に値に戻したい

Tags: vba, excel

Excelでカスタムリボンのドロップダウンリストに選択肢１，選択肢２があり、変更するとそれぞれのマクロが実行します。

選択肢１が選択されている状態から選択肢2を選択したときにシートの状態がマクロ実行に適していない場合、ドロップダウンリストを選択肢１の状態に戻したいのです。

なお、選択肢１のテキストは別シートに保存してあります。

お手数ではございますが、ご教示いただければ幸いに存じます。